# Create sequence for a Conv1D layer

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, convolutional-neural-network, sequence

Im studying the [following tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_anomaly_detection/) on the Keras website and I'm trying to understand how to create a sequence for a Conv1D layer.
This is their method:

```
TIME_STEPS = 288

def create_sequences(values, time_steps=TIME_STEPS):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(values) - time_steps):
        output.append(values[i : (i + time_steps)])
    return np.stack(output)
```

Let's suppose we have `TIME_STEPS = 3` for example, and a dataset which contains `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

If we run that method, we will get a sequence structured as well:

```
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
3 4 5
```

If we train our neural network on these sequence we'll get more training values and it is a great choice, right? But when we test it on the test set, should't we avoid to repeat the values? I made my own method:

```
def create_sequences_test(values, time_steps=TIME_STEPS):
    output = []
    for i in range(len(values) - time_steps):
        output = [values[i: i + time_steps] for i in range(0, len(values) - time_steps, TIME_STEPS)]
    return np.stack(output)
```

Now, if use the same values I should get:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
```

Should't be this one the correct format for the test set?
So I would train the NN creating the sequence with first criteria and then I would create the test with the second one:

```
X_train = create_sequences(dataset[0:500, time_steps=3)
X_test = create_sequences_test(dataset[500:600, time_steps=3)
```